# netscape on linux in 2020

Tags: gtk, browser

How can I get netscape on linux running in 2020?

It's for a project of mine and also nostalgia.

I have downloaded the latest netscape navigator 9.0 i386 and extracted it, but I am unable to start it.

./navigator
./navigator-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I get thois working? do I need docker or something?

Im on arch linux 64bit.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ldd` to see what the executable expects to see. Pinpoint all the missing libraries and:

1. Try to find the packets that provide the library files for your distribution and try to download and install them.
2. If the exact version is missing, try linking a fake symbolic link of the exact filename to the .so library that resembles it most closely.
3. If you still fail to find something like this, look for a deb/rpm/whatever packet that contains that outdated library and install it manually (you might want just to peek inside the deb/rpm with `mc` and copy this one file you need. In this case you might run into the .so not having other .so's that it was compiled against so you might want to start this procedure from no. 1 **for that particular library**.
4. If this fails (with enough work it should work - the system calls for 32/64 kernels have not changed in ages - this is a compatibility matter for the whole Linux kernel) you might want to install the old Linux distro under which this did run and compile the library, or even the entire Netscape package statically, and use this statically linked file on the new system.
5. Conversely you can use a source package on the new system from the old system that did support the product, and build (and link against new libraries) it on the new system.
6. If for some reason this does not work, find, or build a Docker container with the required product - this should really be the way to go, as Docker has been created for exactly this purpose.

This should get you going. Most of cases I needed to run some old binary blob with missing libraries, a fake symbolic link (I would usually put them in /use/local/lib/fake to keep track of those) usually did the trick, but sometimes I did run into missing symbols. Also look out for 64/32 bit differences. 64bit x86 code is totally different from 32bit x86. Yet another issue might be the fact that a package like Netscape has many binary files, and most of them need to be checked with `ldd`.

(BTW - is it really nostalgia, not sheer necessity?)

Comment: Why would using old netscape be a necessity?

Answer (score 1):

You need an i686 version of the GTK2 library. You haven't specified your distro, so it's hard to say how you can install it.

In Fedora 33 that would be:

```
dnf install gtk2.i686
```

For Ubuntu/Debian/Mint/etc. this will probably work:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: That got me a little further, I am missing mozjs.so now, heres a full list of all the stuff im missing. I can't find half this stuff in my repos.. a lot of it is obsolete
http://pastebin.com/zxBSrnxc

Comment: It turns out I do have libmozjs installed, same for a lot of these libs, at least the ones that exist in my repos.

it;'s just not recognizing them, what should i do?

Comment: @sugonddesenuts How does it not recognize it? Can you post the error?